# how to solve problem of not seeing ios simulator?

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

I have a interesting issue. When I run the command:
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone X"

My simulator running in background, even the remote debug page on google chrome opens and I can see in the terminal that it loads the data from bundle but I can't see the simulator itself.

It is also in the tasks in task monitor, I tried to close the task and run again, also did shut down and still it is similar and I can't see the simulator.

Any idea?

Comment: I know this sounds silly, but have you accidentally dragged it off screen? (I've done this before). If so, the following may help. When iOS Simulator is selected, click `Window > Physical Size`. This will then move the simulator back on to the screen.

Comment: I just tried to open it with xcode and it working fine now.

Comment: Still when I am using the command line to open the simulator, it is hidden...

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Xcode before launching react-native run-ios